# CSS - selectors accessibility

Tags: css, css-selectors

All,

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this simple code. Its fairly basic CSS but the browser (FF) totally ignores the last CSS selection code.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="cat_box01"> 
    <a href="#"><img src="i/cat/cat_img01.jpg" /></a>
    <class="sizes_txt">Sizes:</class> 
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#cat_box01 {
    background: rgba(255,43,43,1); /* colouring the background as a test */
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    left: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}


#cat_box01 a img {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}


#cat_box01 .sizes_txt {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;    
}
```

Its the `#cat_box01 .sizes_txt` syntax that is not run. What is it that I am doing wrong here? Cheers for helping a newbie :)

Comment: Please fix your code paste.  The answer depends on what your css selectors look like.  If the above is correct, then you're missing the # on it.

Comment: thanks ehudokai, the # was being used to close the code instead of showing up in the code. It somehow got resolved. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<class>` is not a valid dom element

use `<span class="sizes_txt"> </span>` instead

Comment: thanks a million jondavidjohn. I need to visit Sitepoint again and refamiliarize myself with span & class. Cheers